# How can I see all the data that solr is indexing?

Tags: java, solr, chef-infra

So I have a solr server running as part of a chef server. Some of my nodes just aren't coming up in searches. I can use `?q=*:*` to show the documents but most of the chef data is indexed as dynamicFields, so I don't see it in the xml documents.

I'm hoping that if I can find a way to see either:

- what's coming into solr as it's indexed or
- the full set of indexed documents with their dynamic fields

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case it was because my dynamicFields were set store=false. Setting them to true got me what I was looking for which made the search issue a lot more clear.

Comment: IMHO the answer by rfeak was the correct one. You should really tick his answer rather than your own.

Comment: This answer wasn't mine but rather from hossman on #solr. Hossman wasn't interested in submitting it to SO, so I included it here incase anyone else had the same issue. I up-voted rfeak's answer, but ultimately it was not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 26):

Luke may help: https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke. You can point it at the Solr index and see what's in there.

Last time I checked, you could run it right from the web and just point it at the index.

Answer (score 8):

As rfeak said, you can use Luke to inspect your index. Solr comes with a [built-in Luke handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler).